# How to draw lines based on intervals in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, intervals, subplot

I have these three lists

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
evens = [2,4,6,8,10]
all_nums = [2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9]
```

I need to first draw a line showing the values in `all_nums`, and then draw the other two lines that connect the values in `odds` and `evens`.

For example, after I first draw the line of `all_nums`, I got
[image]

And my final expected graph should be
[image]

I am not sure how to draw the red and green lines as they are produced based on an "interval 2" on the x-axis with respect to the blue line.

I have created a [repl.it](https://repl.it/talk/share/draw_lines_with_interval/58589) with my current code.

Note, my real project is more complicated than this example, in which the first line looks like
[image]
And I need to connect all the valley points and all the peak points, so I cannot simply apply tricks like changing `odds = [1,3,5,7,9]` to `odds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` when drawing, as I wish the curve can also be smooth in the connection between points.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this for the even and odd lines. odd looks 1:1 and even looks like y-2.

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]
evens = [2,4,6,8,10]
all_nums = [2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9]
even_sep=[]
odd_sep=[]
plt.plot(range(len(all_nums)), all_nums, label='odds and evens')
for draw_num_iter in range(len(all_nums)):
  draw_num = all_nums[draw_num_iter]
  plt.annotate(draw_num, xy=(draw_num_iter, draw_num), size=20)
for i in range(len(evens)):
  even_sep.append(evens[i]-2)
plt.plot(even_sep,evens,'ro-')
for i in range(len(odds)):
  odd_sep.append(odds[i])
plt.plot(odd_sep,odds,'g')  
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I realized that I did not clarify my needs very clearly. I am new to matplotlib and the only way I learned to draw a curve is by putting the `range(len(a_list))` as the first argument for plt.plot(), making me think that we must draw a curve continuously on the x-axis. I learned found out that the first argument to plt.plot() can just be the x-coordinates I wish to draw, so  I actually just have to set `odds` or `evens` as the first argument to plt.plot and correspondingly the second argument and that satisfies my needs. I vote to close this question.